# Pagination on category.php not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I use custom permalinks /%category%/%postname%/
On a category's page (category.php) I use pagination, for example, /shops/paged/2 and get 404 error

P.S. If I go to /shops/paged/1 it works
P.P.S Use custom query WP_Query and wp_pagenavi()

```
global $paged;
if (get_query_var( 'paged' ))
    $my_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
else {
    if( get_query_var( 'page' ) )
        $my_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    else
        $my_page = 1;
    set_query_var( 'paged', $my_page );
    $paged = $my_page;
}
$args = array(array('posts_per_page'   => 2, 'paged'            => $paged, 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name'    => 'my_category_nicename'));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

...

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):

...
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to modify the main loop on your category page instead of breaking out a new loop. The main loop of the category you're in doesn't have a page 2 so it never shows the category.php file that you modified, instead the 404 template is loaded.

In the example below I use `pre_get_posts` to check if we're on a category page and change the number of posts per page to 2.

```
function wpse_modify_category_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_category() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        } 
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_modify_category_query' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed 'posts_per_page'   => 2 and added your function into functions.php, removed if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) { ... I also get 404 error on the second page :(

Comment: If you removed posts_per_page what were you hoping it would do?

Comment: I tried with 'posts_per_page' => 2 and 'posts_per_page' => 0 and 'posts_per_page' => -1 and without it. It didn't work. Could you give me an example of correct WP query for this function?

Comment: Im sorry, Nathan, wordpress thinks, that I want to load a detail page of my post instead pagination. Is it correct behavior of it? I added you function, my WP query contains the line 'posts_per_page' => 2 and I am still getting 404 page. Please, help me :(